# Add external .so library to jni project with nar-maven-plugin

Tags: java, c, maven, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have `file.c` which I want to include to my Java application.
I've created `JNI` module and included it to application with `nar-maven-plugin`.

Here's it's configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
    <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <libraries>
            <library>
                <type>jni</type>
                <narSystemPackage>my.package.nativelib</narSystemPackage>
            </library>
        </libraries>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After I run `mvn clean install`, it creates `libmy-native-lib.so` file.

I managed to reach C-functions from Java, but there's one problem: `file.c` uses external `libexternal.so` library (which is included in `file.c` as `#include "external.h"`), and when it reaches  any function from `external.h` it fails with "symbol lookup error".

I tried using

```
static {
    System.load("/usr/lib/libexternal.so");
}
```

and

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("external");
}
```

but nothing seems to be working.

So how can I add external *.so library to JNI project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here to see how to deal with JNI and shared libraries:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-023/

What you need to do is to link your shared library (JNI) with one that is used by JNI code.

Then, you can provide this library with your code, or you can require for user to have it installed in system (e.g. via packages).

Have fun with JNI

Comment: As I understand, you don't have *.so library here, you have another *.c file. Isn't it quite different?

Comment: This another file "c/recipeNo023_AnotherFunction.c" is compiled as shared library. Then, "c/recipeNo023_HelloWorld.c" is linked with this shared library. You can take a look at what is exactly happening here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo023

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. I'm a total noob in C. When I try to run second command I get cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-install_name’

Comment: you can remove this option. I guess it's some remaining stuff from my macOS version